# Implement Rewrite Module to have ApplicationName with querystring

Tags: query-string, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the URL to have application name + querystring? For example I have a web application with the following querystring

```
mywebsite/default.aspx?UserName=xyz
```

How can I have URL with the folllowing

```
mywebsite?xyz
```

I have managed to implement RewriteModule using HttpApplication on Begin_request event and currently I can use this query

```
http://mywebsite/?xyz
```

Is there a way to have the url without `/`?

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
rewrite ^/default\.aspx\?UserName=(.*)$ /?$1 last;
```